# Laravel and Remote Database Dropping

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-connection

I have a Larvel 4.2 app running (Digital Ocean) and a remote database on Google Cloud SQL. (I know being on the same network would be better, but this is just the way it is for now) The database is mapped fine but about 1 in 20 page loads the app server doesn't connect to the database. Is there a way to "keep the connection alive" between the two, or maybe I'm missing something? Any help is always greatly appreciated. Thanks, folks!

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx',
        'database'  => 'mydb',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'mypassword',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be more helpful to find the solution, is to understand why the 1/20 loads fail? Does it display an error (e.g. too many connections or connection timeout)?

You can keep the connection alive by using **persistent connections** but without understanding the problem, it may perhaps aggravate it further (so use with caution).

**Here's how to implement Peristent Connections:**
In your `database.php` file, add the following line to your mysql connection:

`'options' => [\PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true]`

For more info, check out this [Laracasts response](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/persistent-connection-to-mysql-database-in-laravel-30-50-connection-pooling)

Comment: Worked perfectly! A few hundred requests made with 0 failed responses. 

I was getting "Failure to connect to mysql database" error. 

I feel like I should buy you lunch!!